# Keeping track of operations performed by database users

Tags: mysql, database, oracle11g, mysql-5.6

I have three users for my database with several privileges. I want to keep a record of every user's actions. How can I track which operations have been performed by which users?

Comment: 1. Oracle and mysql are 2 different products. Pls remove one of them from your tags. 2. The 3 users you have, are they database level users (3 accounts in db) or application level users (1 account in db)?

Answer (score 0):

first Crate following table for department table contain dno,dname,loc.

```
create table dept_log
(
    userCode number(5),
    userEvent varchar2(10),
    edate date,
    odno number(7),
    odname  varchar2(10),
    oloc  varchar2(10),
    ndno number(7),
    ndname  varchar2(10),
    nloc  varchar2(10)  
)
```

Now Create a Trigger fire after insert, update, and delete.

```
create trigger tri_keep_track_on_operation
after insert or delete or update
on dept
for each row
begin

    if inserting then
        insert into dept_log values(usercode,'insert',sysdate,null,null,null,:new.deptno,:new.dname,:new.loc);
        dbms_output.put_line(' AFTER INSERT ');

    elsif deleting then
        insert into dept_log values(usercode,'delete',sysdate,:old.deptno,:old.dname,:old.loc,null,null,null);
        dbms_output.put_line(' AFTER DELETE ');
    elsif updating then
        insert into dept_log values(usercode,'update',sysdate,:old.deptno,:old.dname,:old.loc,:new.deptno,:new.dname,:new.loc);
        dbms_output.put_line(' AFTER UPDATE ');
    end if;

end;
/
```

I hope help you.